# how to make burp suite the proxy for all interfaces of pc?

Tags: security, proxy, burp

is there a way for burpsuite to be the proxy for all the inerfaces not just the webbrowser related

To be like wireshark

Answer (score 1):

From Control Panel/Windows Start Menu, search for “Internet Options” and follow the below steps.

Internet Option > Connection > LAN settings > uncheck Autodetect settings and Use script setting > check Use manual proxy > provide the address as “127.0.0.1” and port as “8080” or whatever address and port you have configured in Burp proxy options > Ensure the option “bypass localhost” option is unchecked to capture all communication > then click the Ok button for all open windows.

You will be able to capture all communication except for some applications which have an inbuilt proxy or VPN like Riot game applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how we can capture requests through applications then in my opinion, why not setup a system proxy through system setting. Set it to  burp suite proxy which is generally localhost:8080.